# How to set sort indicator for QTableView programatically?

Tags: qt, qtableview

```
TableView *TableView = new TableView();
TableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
TableView->horizontalHeader()->setSortIndicator(header_index, Qt::AscendingOrder);
TableView->horizontalHeader()->setSortIndicatorShown(true);
```

I am not able to see the indicator when I tried to set the sort indicator in qt programmatically. 
Do you know how the set the sort indicator (up/down arrow) in the header while sorting is being done in the `QTableView`?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: I am not able to see the indicator when I tried to set the sort indicator in qt programmatically. Do you know how the set the sort indicator(up/down arrow)in the header while sorting is being done in the tableview?

Comment: Hard to tell from that little piece of code. I would advise you to debug this part of your code step by step and compare the values with the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#setSortIndicator). Maybe your `header_index` is invalid? Maybe some other part of your code changes the behavior to something else?

Comment: I know this is an old question but I am running into this same issue, or at least I thought I did. I added the same line setSortIndicatorShown(true) and couldn't see the indicator but it actually turned out to be a scaling issue with running on a 4K monitor. I found this to be the case because my check boxes are also getting scaled into oblivion. By dragging the GUI onto a different monitor I can see the check boxes and the sort indicators but they are microscopic :-(